# How to copy data from one csv to another with respect to header names in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two CSV files one with certain columns and rows, the second one has just one row with headers in it, The headers in the second file has more headers than first but includes all the headers from the first file. 
I want to fill the columns in the second file when it matches the header from the first file.
The first file is a raw data file which has 20 columns with 100,000 rows that need to be copied to the working file that has 30 columns(20 columns are same as raw). The working file also has no data in it except column headers.
I am able to copy the data with the code below but it but it changes the sequence of columns.I want the sequence of columns in working file intact.
I am pretty new to the language, I would really appreciate any help.

The code i am using right now is:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
def concatenate(indir = "", outfile = "",outdf=""):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    for fileName in fileList:
        print(fileName)
        df=pd.read_csv(fileName,low_memory=False)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatdf=pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatdf.to_csv(outfile, index=False)
concatenate(indir = "xyz.csv", outfile = "abc.csv")
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. Can u post the content of two files and the results you want?

Comment: I don't know if I am allowed to do that with office reports but let me try making it a bit more clear. I have two files one with Raw Data with certain columns and values it has numeric values as well as alphabetical names, another one is my working file where I will do all the classification with this raw data. It just has headers. Working File's Headers contains all the headers that raw data has which we manually have to copy from Raw data. I want to copy those values through python while maintaining the sequence of columns in Working file.

Answer (score 1):

consider dataframes `abc` and `xyz`

```
xyz = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[1, 2, 3], c=[1, 2, 3], d=[1, 2, 3]))
abc = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('artbnckld'))

xyz

   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3

abc 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, r, t, b, n, c, k, l, d]
Index: []
```

---

```
abc.append(xyz)[abc.columns.tolist()]

     a    r    t    b    n    c    k    l    d
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0
2  3.0  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

You can then export to a csv file

```
abc.append(xyz)[abc.columns.tolist()].to_csv()

,a,r,t,b,n,c,k,l,d
0,1.0,,,1.0,,1.0,,,1.0
1,2.0,,,2.0,,2.0,,,2.0
2,3.0,,,3.0,,3.0,,,3.0
```

Comment: I have 20+ columns and 100,000 rows, i can write columns but can't type values. Bear with me as i am still learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

pandas is a great tool, but is overkill here. csv module is enough and `DictReader` and `DictWriter` do what you need automatically:

Assumptions:

- inputs:

  - The output file template contains initially the headers in its first line
  - you want to process a list of input files that contains subsets of the headers of the output file
- output:

  - the output file is populated with data from the input files with respect of field names

Possible code:

```
def populate(outfile, infilelist)
    # First of all read output file field names:
    with open(outfile) as fd:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
        names = rd.fieldnames

    # Reopen output file in append mode to populate if from the files of infilelist
    with open(outfile, "a") as fdout:
        wr = csvDictWriter(fdout, fieldnames = names)
        # loop over the input files:
        for filename in infilelist:
            with open(filename) as fd:
                rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
                # simply copy the rows, one at a time
                for row in rd:
                    wr.writerow(row)
```

This algorithm allows to add data even if the output file contains more that the header line, and can process huge data because (apart from the file buffers) only one line is kept in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am able to run the code and it run without any errors but it is not doing anything.

Comment: @AnkitSati: if it does not do what is expected, just add trace prints for for exactly are `outfile`, `infilelist`, and then inside the loop what `filename` were found. **I** have not **your** folders ;-)

Comment: just two files Raw_Data an Working_File, Working_File is outfile

Comment: In you have only one file, why do shown code loop on all csv files in one folder?

Comment: Sorry, It was done as a precaution just in case if I have multiple files, but it turned out to be a stretch. It would only be one file. I just have to copy data from Raw to working after matching columns.

Comment: Simply remove the loop on input files, or pass the only input file as a singleton list. That should be a trivial task now.

Comment: well the trivial task for you turned out to be pretty hectic for me as i am pretty new into this. I have removed the loop and it still not working. Do i have to specify column header names in rd.fieldnames()?